# HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous during recordTransaction

Tags: corda

I am testing Corda 4.1 Open Source with Zone Constraints and I have 4 nodes which is Node A, Node B, Node C and Notary (the Notary is a CE version of Corda 4.1)

I run the *IssueFlow* to create **StateA** from Node B to Node A. 
And in the IssueFlow.Responder after commit the transaction Node A subFlow a *TestFlow* to update the **StateA** which will add Node C to the participants of **StateA**.

This is the code in IssueFlow.Responder

```
@InitiatedBy(IssueFlow.Initiator::class)
class Responder(val otherFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val flow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherFlow) {
            @Suspendable
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {
                // Custom validation here
            }
        }

        val stx = subFlow(flow)
        val waitForLedgerCommit = subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherFlow, stx.id))

        executableAfterCommit(waitForLedgerCommit)
        return waitForLedgerCommit
    }

    @Suspendable
    private fun executableAfterCommit(stx: SignedTransaction) {
        val listOfStateA = stx.tx.outputsOfType<StateA>()
        require(listOfStateA.size == 1) { "Only one document of StateA is allowed in the transaction." }
        val stateA = listOfStateA.single()

        subFlow(TestFlow.Initiator(listOf(stateA.linearId.id.toString())))
    }
}
```

In TestFlow I will update some information for **StateA** and add Node C as another participant but I want only NodeA and NodeB to sign.
The code as follow:

```
object TestFlow {

    @InitiatingFlow
    @StartableByRPC
    class Initiator(private val linearId: String) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

        override val progressTracker: ProgressTracker()
        val window by lazy { TimeWindow.withTolerance(currentClock.instant(), 30.minutes) }

        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

            val stx = collectSignatures(verifyAndSign(build()))
            val sessions = transaction.sessionsOfParticipants()
            return subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx, sessions))
        }

        private fun build(): TransactionBuilder {

            val statesIn = queryByLinear(listOf(linearId.toUUID())).single()
            val stateOut = stateIn.changeData("field1").addParticipants(NodeC)

            val result = TransactionBuilder(firstNotary).apply {
                // Add inputs
                withItems(statesIn)
                // Add outputs
                withItems(StateAndContract(stateOut, StateAContract.CONTRACT_ID))
                // Signer only NodeA and NodeB
                val listOfSigner = listOf(statesIn.state.data, stateOut)
                        .selectKeysOf(addNodeA = true, addNodeB = true)
                        .toList()
                // Add commands
                addCommand(StateAContract.Commands.Test(), listOfSigner)
                setTimeWindow(window)
            }

            return result.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub)
        }

        private fun verifyAndSign(transaction: TransactionBuilder): SignedTransaction {
            transaction.verify(serviceHub)
            return serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transaction)
        }

        @Suspendable
        private fun collectSignatures(transaction: SignedTransaction): SignedTransaction {
            val signers = excludeNotary(groupPublicKeysByWellKnownParty(serviceHub, transaction.getMissingSigners()), transaction).map { it.key }
            return subFlow(CollectSignatureInitiator(transaction, signers))
        }
    }

    @InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
    class Responder(private val otherFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
            return subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherFlow))
        }
    }

    /**
     * Collect signature initiating flow
     */
    @InitiatingFlow
    class CollectSignatureInitiator(private val transaction: SignedTransaction, private val signers: List<Party>) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
            val sessions = signers.map { initiateFlow(it) }
            return subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(transaction, sessions))
        }
    }

    /**
     * Collect signature responder flow
     */
    @InitiatedBy(CollectSignatureInitiator::class)
    class CollectSignatureResponder(private val session: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
            return subFlow(object : SignTransactionFlow(session) {
                override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) {
                    subFlow(ValidateDocument(session, stx))
                    return
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

and TestFlow throw an error in Node C as follow:

```
[INFO ] 2019-09-27T01:54:42,534Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.call - Transaction dependencies resolution completed. {fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=1413cfc2-c522-45be-90d3-ce593ba3db91, invocation_id=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, invocation_timestamp=2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, origin=OU=NodeA, O=NodeA, L=Bangkok, C=TH, session_id=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, session_timestamp=2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, thread-id=205, tx_id=A083E2C3F0AA98DFCE5D0FD02420EF1A4947FEAEACE2AB1226FF89CA606D19B3}
[INFO ] 2019-09-27T01:54:42,814Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.call - Successfully received fully signed tx. Sending it to the vault for processing. {fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=1413cfc2-c522-45be-90d3-ce593ba3db91, invocation_id=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, invocation_timestamp=2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, origin=OU=NodeA, O=NodeA, L=Bangkok, C=TH, session_id=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, session_timestamp=2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, thread-id=205, tx_id=A083E2C3F0AA98DFCE5D0FD02420EF1A4947FEAEACE2AB1226FF89CA606D19B3}
[INFO ] 2019-09-27T01:54:42,987Z [Node thread-1] corda.flow.run - Flow raised an error: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous. Sending it to flow hospital to be triaged. {fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=1413cfc2-c522-45be-90d3-ce593ba3db91, invocation_id=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, invocation_timestamp=2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, origin=OU=NodeA, O=NodeA, L=Bangkok, C=TH, session_id=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, session_timestamp=2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, thread-id=205, tx_id=A083E2C3F0AA98DFCE5D0FD02420EF1A4947FEAEACE2AB1226FF89CA606D19B3}
[INFO ] 2019-09-27T01:54:42,999Z [Node thread-1] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital.flowErrored - Flow [1413cfc2-c522-45be-90d3-ce593ba3db91] admitted to hospital in state StateMachineState(checkpoint=Checkpoint(invocationContext=InvocationContext(origin=Peer(party=OU=NodeA, O=NodeA, L=Bangkok, C=TH), trace=Trace(invocationId=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, timestamp: 2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, entityType: Invocation, sessionId=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, timestamp: 2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, entityType: Session), actor=null, externalTrace=null, impersonatedActor=null), ourIdentity=OU=BANK, O=SCB3, L=Bangkok, C=TH, sessions={SessionId(toLong=-2182783777352841143)=Initiated(peerParty=OU=NodeA, O=NodeA, L=Bangkok, C=TH, peerFlowInfo=FlowInfo(flowVersion=1, appName=testflow-1.0), receivedMessages=[], initiatedState=Live(peerSinkSessionId=SessionId(toLong=-3936218859034478298)), errors=[], deduplicationSeed=D--3936218859034478298--368822318982290956)}, subFlowStack=[Inlined(flowClass=class com.corda.test.flows.TestFlow$Responder, subFlowVersion=CoreFlow(platformVersion=4), isEnabledTimedFlow=false)], flowState=Started(flowIORequest=Send(sessionToMessage={FlowSessionImpl(counterparty=OU=NodeA, O=NodeA, L=Bangkok, C=TH, sourceSessionId=SessionId(toLong=-2182783777352841143))=768AED61FD2A58D74D7316731407E0600065080E1F3E6397EE4FA5AEFEE79295}), frozenFiber=6C3A73148E4E786591224DA1A0BDCADD704073C8A70CE425769DE7576F43735B), errorState=Clean, numberOfSuspends=5), flowLogic=com.corda.test.flows.TestFlow$Responder@1ad039f4, pendingDeduplicationHandlers=[], isFlowResumed=true, isTransactionTracked=false, isAnyCheckpointPersisted=true, isStartIdempotent=false, isRemoved=false, senderUUID=f5784837-d7a3-45e8-8b4c-9cf286f080b8) {fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=1413cfc2-c522-45be-90d3-ce593ba3db91, invocation_id=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, invocation_timestamp=2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, origin=OU=NodeA, O=NodeA, L=Bangkok, C=TH, session_id=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, session_timestamp=2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, thread-id=205, tx_id=A083E2C3F0AA98DFCE5D0FD02420EF1A4947FEAEACE2AB1226FF89CA606D19B3}
[INFO ] 2019-09-27T01:54:43,005Z [Node thread-1] statemachine.StaffedFlowHospital.invoke - Error 1 of 1: {fiber-id=10000001, flow-id=1413cfc2-c522-45be-90d3-ce593ba3db91, invocation_id=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, invocation_timestamp=2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, origin=OU=NodeA, O=NodeA, L=Bangkok, C=TH, session_id=cb808503-85c2-4c8c-afb7-3d1996f4fc02, session_timestamp=2019-09-27T01:52:36.071Z, thread-id=205, tx_id=A083E2C3F0AA98DFCE5D0FD02420EF1A4947FEAEACE2AB1226FF89CA606D19B3}
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1440) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase.loadValue(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:145) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase.access$loadValue(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:22) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase$transactionalLoadValue$3.invoke(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:160) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase$Transactional$Unknown$valueWithoutIsolationDelegate$1.invoke(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:251) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at kotlin.SafePublicationLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:107) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar:1.2.71-release-64 (1.2.71)]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase$Transactional$Unknown.isPresent(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:249) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase$Transactional.orElse(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:222) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AppendOnlyPersistentMapBase.get(AppendOnlyPersistentMap.kt:40) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService$certificateFromCordaX500Name$1.invoke(PersistentIdentityService.kt:165) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService$certificateFromCordaX500Name$1.invoke(PersistentIdentityService.kt:33) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:224) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:204) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:210) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService.certificateFromCordaX500Name(PersistentIdentityService.kt:164) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(PersistentIdentityService.kt:175) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.node.services.IdentityService$DefaultImpls.wellKnownPartyFromAnonymous(IdentityService.kt:103) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.IdentityServiceInternal$DefaultImpls.wellKnownPartyFromAnonymous(IdentityServiceInternal.kt) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService$wellKnownPartyFromAnonymous$1.invoke(PersistentIdentityService.kt:184) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService$wellKnownPartyFromAnonymous$1.invoke(PersistentIdentityService.kt:33) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:224) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:204) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:210) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.identity.PersistentIdentityService.wellKnownPartyFromAnonymous(PersistentIdentityService.kt:184) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$database$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:158) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$database$2.invoke(AbstractNode.kt:120) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.persistence.AbstractPartyToX500NameAsStringConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(AbstractPartyToX500NameAsStringConverter.kt:23) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.persistence.AbstractPartyToX500NameAsStringConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(AbstractPartyToX500NameAsStringConverter.kt:15) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.JpaAttributeConverterImpl.toRelationalValue(JpaAttributeConverterImpl.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$1.bind(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3162) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3686) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeInserts(ActionQueue.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:824) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:791) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:436) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:399) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:486) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:800) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    at net.corda.node.services.schema.PersistentStateService.persistStatesWithSchema$node(PersistentStateService.kt:48) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.schema.PersistentStateService.persist(PersistentStateService.kt:40) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService.processAndNotify(NodeVaultService.kt:364) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService.access$processAndNotify(NodeVaultService.kt:51) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService$notifyAll$1.invoke(NodeVaultService.kt:213) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.vault.NodeVaultService.notifyAll(NodeVaultService.kt:223) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$Companion$recordTransactions$1.invoke(ServiceHubInternal.kt:106) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$Companion$recordTransactions$1.invoke(ServiceHubInternal.kt:51) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:224) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:204) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:210) ~[corda-node-api-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$Companion.recordTransactions(ServiceHubInternal.kt:60) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.api.ServiceHubInternal$DefaultImpls.recordTransactions(ServiceHubInternal.kt:132) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode$ServiceHubInternalImpl.recordTransactions(AbstractNode.kt:962) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveTransactionFlow.call(ReceiveTransactionFlow.kt:62) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveTransactionFlow.call(ReceiveTransactionFlow.kt:28) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:329) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:314) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveFinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:256) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.ReceiveFinalityFlow.call(FinalityFlow.kt:251) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:329) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:314) ~[corda-core-4.1.jar:?]
    at com.corda.test.flows.TestFlow$Responder.call(TestFlow.kt:226) ~[?:?]
    at com.corda.test.flows.TestFlow$Responder.call(TestFlow.kt:221) ~[?:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:269) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:45) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.1.jar:?]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Flush during cascade is dangerous
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1449) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.6.Final.jar:5.3.6.Final]
    ... 104 more
```

Now what I'm doing to solve this problem is I went to onchain database and truncate the following table

```
- node_info_party_cert
- node_link_nodeinfo_party
- node_info_hosts
- node_infos
```

After truncate these table I restart Node C then let it resume from node checkpoints and everything works.

Sometimes the error happens on Both Node B and Node C.

I'm using the same code and test in the CE environment but I didn't found this error.

The question is

- What is the root cause of this error?
- What was Corda is trying to do when recordTransactions?
- What is the proper way to solve this problem?

Comment: This could be an issue with how the Corda node interacts with Hibernate during persistence of an entity that has cascade relationships. Could you also share the definitions of your states & the associated Hibernate entities, please?

Comment: What you encountered was actually a bug, which we've fixed. You can try to run your code with the nightly build of OS 4.3 (`4.3-SNAPSHOT`) and let us know if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved with the latest version of Corda OS 4.3.

You can get update your dependencies at build.gradle, and point it to newer version of Corda.